# Badge proposal: award after several consecutive accepted answers

Tags: discussion, badges

What do you think of a series of badges assigned after a number of consecutive accepted answers?
Something like:

**Hungry** - 10 or more consecutive accepted answers
**Greedy** - 20 ore more consecutive accepted answers
**Cannibal** - 30 or more consecutive accepted answers

a variant could be respectively: **Shooter**, **Marksman**, **Sniper**.

I don't know if it can be easily implemented and I have not delved yet the number of badges the top users would get <sup>*</sup>; it's just an idea, that's it.

For what I superficially see on Jon Skeet profile, **they are not easy to get**.

Any thought?

<sup>* it can be done with the SE API, any idea using Odata?</sup>

Comment: My record is 6.  10 would be very difficult I'd imagine.

Comment: I saw a 12 on Jon Skeet but I have checked just the first pages of his monstrous profile.

Comment: @system, are you ordering by newest?

Comment: @jjn yep, http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet#qpage_1-anpage_17-qsort_views-ansort_newest

Comment: @system, wow.  That's impressive.

Comment: It is easy to get, just delete answers that didn't get accepted.  As usual, badges are supposed to reward positive behavior.  Deleting good but neglected answers isn't.

Comment: @Hans Passant - my thoughts exactly...

Comment: My longest streak is 5 in a row.  I'd have to delete at least 10 answers just to get 10 lined up, and I'd have to delete many, many more to get 20 or 30 lined up.  Fun little metric, though!

Comment: @system I hate bejeweled with the passion of a thousand burning suns!  Could have something to do with my red/green colorblindness.  Even my 4 year old is vastly better at finding matches than I am.  :'-(

Comment: @Polly @jjnguy added some data just for fun

Comment: @Hans you have collected 14 consecutive answers, not that bad :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't explain how this behavior is beneficial to stack overflow, or how this badge would encourage behaviors we want people to engage in.

#### Bad behavior it might encourage:

- It *might* encourage people to delete their own answers that are not accepted
- It *might* encourage people to attack other answers in an attempt to get others to delete them so their answer is accepted
- It *might* encourage users to <strike>abuse</strike> badger question askers in attempt to get their answers accepted
- It *might* discourage people from answering questions that they don't think will be accepted, including quick and easy "here you go, hope this helps, this is all I have time for" answers that get you going without giving you the perfect answer

#### Good behavior it might encourage:

- It *might* encourage users to spend more time crafting quality answers
- It *might* encourage users to re-visit answers that weren't accepted, and work on them

On balance it probably doesn't meet the goal of badges.

Comment: @system I suppose.  If I *have* to.  ;-D

Comment: @system I came up with a few possibly good behaviors, so it doesn't look so hopeless...

Answer (score 6):

This badges proposal is *blatantly flawed* for the valid reasons given in the [other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78409/badge-proposal-award-after-several-consecutive-accepted-answers/78424#78424).
Anyway, curious about this metric, I have collected some data using the [SE API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help).

Here is the **SUPER COMBO** charts of the top 100 Stack Overflow users <sup>* ** ***</sup> :

<sup>* this chart does not prove anything, other users out of top 100 could have done better</sup>
<sup>** the two dates represent the lower bound and upper bound of the combo</sup>
<sup>*** in an hypothetical honest world, getting those badges without cheating would be tough</sup>

*TL;DR*
The most incredible combo is by [Paolo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino) with an impressive [20X consecutive correct answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino#qpage_1-anpage_2-qsort_views-ansort_newest).

> ### user #1: Jon Skeet
>
> **11X Combo: 2**
>   2010-08-12 16:31:36 : ++someVariable Vs. someVariable++ in Javascript
>   2010-08-12 21:35:41 : How can a StringBuilder best be converted to a String[]?
>
> 2010-09-23 15:36:56 : php DateTime timezone for Columbus Ohio
>   2010-09-24 07:02:05 : How to use LINQ to generate new type of objects
>
> **12X Combo: 4**
>   2009-02-10 10:15:10 : C# volatile double
>   2009-02-10 19:40:02 : How do I get all the base types in an assembly?
>
> 2010-09-06 09:13:05 : Do long class names affect the size of a XAP file?
>   2010-09-06 17:26:15 : C#: Convert T to T[]
>
> 2010-10-14 18:36:45 : Is it worth to write a programming book and sell it ?
>   2010-10-15 10:51:48 : HttpWebRequest submit
>
> 2011-01-11 08:01:19 : Small http server using java?
>   2011-01-11 17:23:35 : When is .net object = null game for garbage collection?  Does scope matter?
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2009-08-12 19:09:29 : Is there a way to add something like the params option for generic types?
>   2009-08-13 10:23:32 : Making an URL out of modified database fields
>
> ---
>
> ### user #2: Marc Gravell
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-12-09 06:50:35 : LINQ2SQL Alternatives for MonoDevelop
>   2010-12-10 07:21:46 : String restriction within protobuf
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2009-01-19 11:08:00 : foreach to linq tip wanted
>   2009-01-19 19:56:57 : Extend a TypeConverter
>
> ---
>
> ### user #3: Alex Martelli
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-05-13 14:49:46 : python create object and add attributes to it
>   2010-05-15 05:24:59 : Javascript or Python? beginner getting up to speed
>
> ---
>
> ### user #5: Hans Passant
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-03-29 17:57:25 : Inconsistency in passing objects from VBA to .NET via COM
>   2010-03-30 11:15:56 : How do I change Windows Service environment path
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2010-09-17 19:24:57 : Setting DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Value in formLoad? Impossible?
>   2010-09-18 19:36:04 : .NET user control for use in a web browser and prevent design time use
>
> **14X Combo: 1**
>   2010-07-07 22:11:48 : How could I export application settings into a portable file? [C#]
>   2010-07-08 16:01:03 : FlushFileBuffers as good as CloseHandle then CreateFile at saving data to disk?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #7: Nick Craver
>
> **11X Combo: 11**
>   2010-04-27 19:45:48 : Documentation on jQuery-UI widgets
>   2010-04-28 02:06:09 : CSS Hover on parent list Item only
>
> 2010-05-11 02:03:59 : jQuery Change background of input field if text getting replaced
>   2010-05-11 19:55:32 : jQuery parent()
>
> 2010-05-29 11:28:29 : View list of all JavaScript variables in Google Chrome Console
>   2010-05-30 11:30:01 : Help with jQuery issue
>
> 2010-06-19 11:13:49 : Get the selected text of a web page in google chrome extension
>   2010-06-20 00:40:48 : Visual Studio 2010 MSDN Licensing?
>
> 2010-06-28 14:43:43 : jQuery: Fade in delay on Load
>   2010-06-29 02:27:53 : JQUery looping through each table row
>
> 2010-08-30 14:05:53 : Problem with RegisterClientScriptInclude and RegisterClientScriptBlock
>   2010-08-31 00:45:45 : trigger select box to drop down on clicking another element
>
> 2010-09-02 12:00:16 : Why JQuery's .post returns no data?
>   2010-09-02 20:03:24 : Jquery Expand image height and width 20% on hover
>
> 2010-09-09 22:50:00 : Confirm browser back button else stay on page
>   2010-09-10 11:45:26 : jQuery/Javascript getting all attributes from an element and pass it to another
>
> 2010-10-04 23:37:54 : How To I Replace New Elements Added To A Page With Jquery
>   2010-10-05 09:49:38 : How does stackoverflow calculates answer accept time limit of 14 mins using jquery?
>
> 2010-11-29 10:14:51 : How to get value of pressed button (jQuery UI button-checkboxes)
>   2010-11-29 13:17:20 : jQuery: Loading html file from the server in desktop application
>
> 2010-12-20 12:00:47 : JS/jQuery/PHP: trying to generate an URL using PHP variables
>   2010-12-20 21:30:44 : jquery Why do these appended divs ignore their css?
>
> **12X Combo: 8**
>   2010-07-20 10:26:24 : how to use jquery.validate plugin in cakephp form
>   2010-07-20 23:53:15 : Jquery/javascript detect and capture page refresh events?
>
> 2010-07-30 01:04:23 : What well known JavaScript libraries are located on CDN's, and what are the URLs'?
>   2010-07-30 15:25:20 : Remote IIS Management
>
> 2010-09-17 13:52:41 : What's the difference between : 1. (ajaxStart and ajaxSend) and 2. (ajaxStop and ajaxComplete)?
>   2010-09-19 23:57:50 : toggle a css color on hover
>
> 2010-10-17 22:30:46 : jQuery template() for putting a URL into src= attribute of image
>   2010-10-18 11:48:43 : JQuery and printArea — customizing print output
>
> 2010-10-28 10:33:14 : get previous selected dropdown item
>   2010-10-28 22:26:45 : Help me understand whats wrong with my javascript.
>
> 2010-11-15 23:12:10 : Opposite of "scrollTop" in jQuery
>   2010-11-16 10:51:15 : How to add element with old element's html and remove old element in Jquery with new?
>
> 2010-11-17 12:29:34 : jQuery: live() vs delegate()
>   2010-11-17 19:52:18 : jQuery .wrap() question
>
> 2010-11-20 14:56:57 : How to grab label value from checked option with jQuery
>   2010-11-21 09:28:24 : File API: What browsers support the slice method?
>
> **13X Combo: 5**
>   2010-05-11 23:30:32 : How to do custom jquery lives in 1.4.1?
>   2010-05-12 21:01:49 : Function Triggered before fadeOut(); is finished
>
> 2010-06-23 16:56:50 : jQuery & drop down menu hiding divs (or textareas)
>   2010-06-24 20:15:13 : Jquery Remove() after hide()
>
> 2010-08-20 10:00:28 : stop jQuery double-binding click event (best practice)
>   2010-08-20 18:07:01 : jQuery dialog no longer works after I append to
>
> 2010-09-01 11:51:54 : IE8 error with javascript file which has jQuery functions?
>   2010-09-01 14:46:12 : How do I add a exception to the document for a menu system, using JQuery?
>
> 2010-12-07 14:23:46 : Why isn't this working on Internet Explorer? [jQuery, radio, selectors]
>   2010-12-08 01:25:17 : check to see if first element is , if so addClass. if not, do nothing.
>
> **14X Combo: 2**
>   2010-07-01 10:58:01 : jQuery mouse out and not hiding a particular element
>   2010-07-02 03:36:32 : In IE Javascript execution speed is slower than Firefox, Safari and Chrome....
>
> 2010-10-21 21:50:27 : jquery check all checkboxes and add class to rows?
>   2010-10-22 09:22:35 : jQuery Ajax Success Call jQuery UI
>
> **17X Combo: 1**
>   2010-08-05 13:05:52 : jQuery: Get .timeago() to work on elements loaded after DOM ready (Ajax)
>   2010-08-05 23:58:10 : Dynamic Links and jQuery Lightbox issue : Loading image in lightbox...completely stumped!!
>
> **19X Combo: 1**
>   2010-12-14 12:08:34 : Looping queue with jQuery
>   2010-12-14 21:45:01 : IE8 breaking on hover of select box's options
>
> ---
>
> ### user #8: tvanfosson
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2009-08-29 17:14:47 : How can I make a blogger.com template?
>   2009-08-30 21:02:08 : How to compare just the date, not the timestamp using LINQ
>
> ---
>
> ### user #9: cletus
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-03-04 22:59:23 : Parsing Malformed HTML with PHP Dom
>   2010-03-06 10:05:37 : Being stuck in between two jobs, what to do? Should i just dump my former job?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #10: BalusC
>
> 11X Combo: 1
>   2010-07-26 15:50:35 : JSP / Servlet HTTP 404 error handling
>   2010-07-27 16:46:29 : Does the jsf lifecycle apply to the outcome facelet when I click a button?
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2010-08-03 17:18:13 : Is jQuery method chaining an example of fluent programming?
>   2010-08-04 14:06:46 : Need help in getting HTML of a website in Java
>
> **16X Combo: 1**
>   2010-11-15 15:06:23 : JSF2.0: ManagedProperty Lifecycle?
>   2010-11-16 17:20:37 : Displaying database result in JSP
>
> ---
>
> ### user #13: VonC
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2009-07-29 13:24:13 : SWT Multiple Monitor Support on Solaris?
>   2009-07-30 18:50:25 : Eclipse Ganymede not validating tag files properly
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2010-04-27 08:50:15 : Traits vs template
>   2010-04-28 14:44:55 : git
>   remove file from the repository
>
> ---
>
> ### user #14: Pascal Thivent
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-02-16 16:50:15 : JPA validation strategy
>   2010-02-17 14:55:57 : Can I use maven to find but not download the latest version of a dependency?
>
> **14X Combo: 1**
>   2010-08-17 20:40:03 : Run Ant task from Maven
>   2010-08-18 17:15:50 : hibernate validator
>
> ---
>
> ### user #15: Mark Byers
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-08-20 14:20:20 : Python: Unpack from hex to double
>   2010-08-22 01:54:36 : Regular expressions split and match
>
> ---
>
> ### user #19: CMS
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2010-07-29 02:31:33 : callback function return global object :/
>   2010-08-07 20:25:43 : How come eval doesn't have access to the scoped variables under a with statement?
>
> **14X Combo: 2**
>   2010-05-04 14:56:24 : What is happening in Crockford's object creation technique?
>   2010-05-11 06:01:55 : Converting HTML entities to Unicode character in JavaScript?
>
> 2010-06-30 02:22:27 : Is strict mode more performant?
>   2010-07-07 20:39:14 : Appending elements to DOM in a loop structure.
>
> ---
>
> ### user #22: bobince
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-04-15 17:28:04 : jquery ajax encoding problem!
>   2010-04-16 11:00:19 : Can str_replace be safely used on a UTF-8 encoded string if it's only given valid UTF-8 encoded strings as arguments?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #24: Johannes Schaub - litb
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2010-03-12 13:55:13 : Turning temporary stringstream to c_str() in single statement
>   2010-03-15 16:05:05 : Does the compiler optimize the function parameters passed by value?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #25: Pekka
>
> **11X Combo: 2**
>   2010-06-09 15:01:53 : Best practices: displaying text that was input via multi-line text box
>   2010-06-10 11:28:50 : how to use json_encode without PHP 5.2
>
> 2010-11-18 09:56:43 : How to avoid writing include_once() in file again and again for including different class?
>   2010-11-18 20:14:23 : jQuery not working on this page in any browser. I can't figure out why!
>
> ---
>
> ### user #28: KennyTM
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2010-06-12 11:21:55 : How can I determine programmatically that my app is running on an iPhone, iPad or iPhone 4?
>   2010-06-15 06:33:11 : +(void) initialize in objective-c class static variables constructor
>
> ---
>
> ### user #39: OMG Ponies
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-10-22 16:05:50 : SQL Server
>   pull X random records per state
>   2010-10-23 04:12:39 : left join with condition for right table in mysql
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2010-10-25 19:15:19 : Pervasive Sql 10 Join one table, onto another, onto another
>   2010-10-26 19:47:45 : TSQL Naming conventions ~ What's this naming convention called?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #40: CommonsWare
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-10-01 14:09:07 : Playing multiple audio files in Android
>   2010-10-03 18:21:33 : Using the same view on both tabs in Android
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2010-06-17 22:02:49 : android expanded notification view
>   2010-06-20 11:43:08 : ListView items won't show focus when touched
>
> ---
>
> ### user #42: James McNellis
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2010-04-12 00:15:42 : Best way to get ints from a string with whitespace?
>   2010-04-16 15:58:47 : How can char* be a condition in for loop?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #54: Charles Bailey
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2010-08-23 19:36:18 : Function pointer in parameter
>   2010-08-30 08:28:38 : How does it work, Test *pObj = new Test(); as constructor does not return anything
>
> ---
>
> ### user #61: GMan
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-03-03 04:32:58 : Can normal maps be generated from a texture?
>   2010-03-09 21:35:09 : Declare float or cast float?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #70: sepp2k
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2010-10-22 14:47:15 : Comparing list of floats
>   2010-10-23 16:16:54 : How to make this beautiful and short
>
> ---
>
> ### user #71: Paolo Bergantino
>
> **11X Combo: 2**
>   2009-06-08 01:24:36 : Looping inside a loop
>   2009-06-08 19:11:10 : jQuery parent of a parent
>
> 2009-07-03 00:24:17 : javascript onclick remove single checkbox
>   2009-07-06 07:29:43 : how to get selected value of dropdownlist using javascript?
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2009-08-02 21:07:06 : Why would I put an ID on a script tag?
>   2009-08-20 12:12:51 : Is it OK to add your own attributes to HTML elements?
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2009-02-24 02:20:23 : Alter CSS class attributes with javascript?
>   2009-02-26 15:22:36 : Disable other text boxes on input using jQuery
>
> **16X Combo: 1**
>   2009-05-25 08:59:46 : Is binding events in jQuery very expensive, or very inexpensive?
>   2009-05-29 21:46:25 : In Django, how do you retrieve a field of a many-to-many related class?
>
> **20X Combo: 1**
>   2009-08-25 15:04:41 : double $ statement in php
>   2010-01-20 18:54:03 : Can you explain this code?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #77: Greg
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2009-10-20 13:46:27 : onchange event never happens on IE while ok with firefox
>   2009-10-23 10:47:03 : Singleton Pattern with {}?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #80: Henk Holterman
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-03-06 06:57:55 : WPF: Access XAML objects/shapes/path declared using C#
>   2010-03-09 22:00:19 : Entity Framework Update existing foreign Key reference to another
>
> **12X Combo: 1**
>   2009-05-28 10:28:42 : 2D Array of TextBoxes in UserControl
>   2009-06-08 16:52:04 : column order problem in dataGridViews in C#
>
> **14X Combo: 1**
>   2009-04-03 16:58:16 : How to use Unit files in Delphi
>   2009-04-23 03:43:01 : StackOverflowException without recursion or infinite loop?
>
> **18X Combo: 2**
>   2009-06-19 09:47:21 : Winforms RichTextBox Pagesize ?
>   2009-07-06 15:59:42 : Do I need to syncronize thread access to an int
>
> 2009-08-12 20:34:58 : Question regarding return types with collections
>   2009-08-29 18:34:50 : Multi-Threading Question adding an Element to a static List
>
> ---
>
> ### user #81: Craig Stuntz
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2010-04-21 13:04:36 : Setting options with Linq
>   2010-04-26 15:53:08 : generate only objectLayer of Entity Framework Model by edmgen tool
>
> ---
>
> ### user #86: patrick dw
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-02-22 13:19:00 : Jquery : Concatenate Values From Two Elements
>   2010-02-24 12:49:39 : Jquery: Find all image links and convert them to some default thumbs?
>
> **12X Combo: 2**
>   2010-02-09 16:01:13 : My unsolved problem in jquery animation
>   2010-02-18 14:13:39 : Jquery ul with many li items seperated to a ul with rest of the li items
>   2010-08-31 02:55:33 : Javacript Validating Currency Amount
>   2010-09-02 15:19:49 : how do i get the id of the  a href which is dynamic in nature in jquery
>
> **13X Combo: 1**
>   2010-06-22 03:22:23 : jQuery Multiple Events
>   2010-06-23 22:35:58 : How do I change the properties of a DOM element based on a property of an adjacent field?
>
> ---
>
> ### user #96: T.J. Crowder
>
> **11X Combo: 1**
>   2010-03-21 15:08:01 : Strange javascript decoding behavior in IE
>   2010-03-23 11:47:07 : Ajax And REST: Can I send an ajax request to a REST service to recieve response?

Comment: Man I'm awesome

Answer (score 1):

Unless it counted deleted answers, this would be very easy to game:

- Find the longest streaks of accepted answers broken by the fewest number of unaccepted
- delete all the unaccepted answers breaking up the streaks.

That doesn't even consider the "ask and answer my own questions" to bump a streak over a threshold, &c.

Comment: ...unless both of those didn't count.

Answer (score 1):

I would be against it, as it promotes deletion of answers. Even non-accepted answer are contributions, and can provide valuable information